# How to retrieve latest Notes inserted to Custom Object

Tags: soql

I have Custom Object that contains many Notes for each record.I want to retrieve the `latest Note` inserted for all the Records.

```
List<CustomObject__c> = [select (select Body from Notes order by Id desc Limit 1) notes,Id from CustomObject__c];
```

The above  Query gives me the Latest Note but it contains Body like

```
(Note: ParentId:.... Body :...... Id: .....)
```

I want to show Body of latest Note in `apex:outputText`

and i also tried below query which gives only Body of Note but not Latest Inserted.

```
List<Note> notes = [Select Body from Note where ParentId in(select Id from CustomObject__c)];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

```
List<Note> notes = [Select Body from Note where ParentId in(select Id from CustomObject__c) order by ParentId,CreatedDate desc];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
List<Note> notes = [Select Body from Note where ParentId in(select Id from CustomObject__c) order by Id desc Limit 1];
```

Comment: Thanks for response. This will give me only one Note for all the records not for each record.